# VB.net re-code this IF structure

Tags: vb.net

well the code works.. the logic has no problem at all but let me tell you.. it is an UGLY piece of code.. was trying to do it via select.. case but couldnt see a way..

the thing is that I need to activate the "Warning" that i get via any of the OR but, there is no way to detect which condition were not met to point it out..

so here it is.. would apprecite if anyone could help me clean it up.

```
If (txt_nombre_plato.Text = "") Then
    MsgBox("Completa el Nombre del Platillo")
    valida_blanco = False
Else
    If (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "CARNES") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "MARISCOS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "PESCADOR") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "PASTAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "PIZZAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "HAMBRUGESAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "SOPAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "BEBIDAS ALCOHOLICAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "BEBIDAS SIN ALCOHOL") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "POSTRES TORTAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "MPOSTRES HELADOS") Then
        MsgBox("Selecciona Sub-Categoria del Platillo")
        valida_blanco = False
    Else
        If (txt_descripcion_plato.Text = "") Then
            MsgBox("Coloca la descripción del Platillo")
            valida_blanco = False
        Else
            If (txt_precio_plato.Text = "") Then
                MsgBox("Coloca el precio del Platillo")
                valida_blanco = False
            Else
                If (inflater_imagen = "") Then
                    MsgBox("Selecciona la imagen del Platillo")
                    valida_blanco = False
                Else
                    If (chk_estado_contorno.Checked) And Lista_contorno.Items.Count = 0 Then MsgBox("Debes Agregar el contorno del Platillo", "Info") : valida_blanco = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar version to Marc's, using a list to hold the error messages, but also a list for the values of `txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text` being checked for, which simplifies that line -

```
    Dim subCategoriaPlatoList As New List(Of String)(New String() {"CARNES", "MARISCOS", "PESCADOR", "PASTAS", "PIZZAS", "HAMBRUGESAS", "SOPAS", "BEBIDAS ALCOHOLICAS", "BEBIDAS SIN ALCOHOL", "POSTRES TORTAS", "MPOSTRES HELADOS"})
    Dim messageStrings As New List(Of String)()

    If (txt_nombre_plato.Text = "") Then
        messageStrings.Add("Completa el Nombre del Platillo")
    End If

    If subCategoriaPlatoList.Contains(txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text) Then
        messageStrings.Add("Selecciona Sub-Categoria del Platillo")
    End If

    If (txt_descripcion_plato.Text = "") Then
        messageStrings.Add("Coloca la descripción del Platillo")
    End If

    If (txt_precio_plato.Text = "") Then
        messageStrings.Add("Coloca el precio del Platillo")
    End If

    If (inflater_imagen = "") Then
        messageStrings.Add("Selecciona la imagen del Platillo")
    End If

    If (chk_estado_contorno.Checked) And Lista_contorno.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Debes Agregar el contorno del Platillo", "Info")
    End If

    valida_blanco = messageStrings.Count = 0
    Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, messageStrings.ToArray())
    MsgBox(message)
```

Comment: @marc id like to accept both answer hehe, thanks Logical, this at least cleans the mess a little bit more.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without else conditions.
This way you are also able to display all errors at once, which I believe is more user friendly:

```
Dim errors As New List(Of String)()

If txt_nombre_plato.Text = "" Then
    errors.Add("Completa el Nombre del Platillo")
End If

If (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "CARNES") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "MARISCOS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "PESCADOR") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "PASTAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "PIZZAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "HAMBRUGESAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "SOPAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "BEBIDAS ALCOHOLICAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "BEBIDAS SIN ALCOHOL") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "POSTRES TORTAS") Or (txt_combo_sub_categoria_plato.Text = "MPOSTRES HELADOS") Then
    errors.Add("Selecciona Sub-Categoria del Platillo")
End If

If txt_descripcion_plato.Text = "" Then
    errors.Add("Coloca la descripción del Platillo")
End If

' etc...

valida_blanco = errors.Count = 0
MsgBox([String].Join(Environment.NewLine, errors))
```